# Unable to detect Hall Effect

Tags: hall-effect

I have watched several videos on the Hall Effect, but when I try to create the effect in my garage I get zero results. As you can see in the attached photo I have a volt meter connected across a metal plate and a battery voltage connected on the other sides. Any ideas on why I am not seeing any Hall Effect voltage? The magnets are two Harbor Freight ceramic magnets. I have tried them in different configurations. I have even tried an strong neodymium, no success.
I am not an electrical engineer so please keep that in mind when answering.
Thank you[image]

Comment: What is the Actual DC or AC output and what did you expect. You may be overpowering the sensor to stay on all the time.

Comment: My meter shows no voltage. I was expecting to see some voltage that would be a portion of the 1.5 volt input voltage.

Comment: How many Different Hall sensors do you believe there are? Are we supposed to guess? Add a link to the data sheet and your schematic

Comment: There is no sensor. What you see in the photo is all there is. I am trying to create my own sensor. The YouTube videos that explain the effect show setups just l the one I have in the photo.

Comment: What video? The Hall coefficient is defined as the ratio of the induced electric field to the product of the current density and the applied magnetic field. A conductor will shunt the E field to a very small DC voltage uV

Comment: https://youtu.be/R9Jpi2bIiU8

Comment: Here’s a shorter one, but they all pretty much say the same thing. https://youtu.be/wpAA3qeOYiI

Comment: It’s the current added that is flowing that is detected by Lorenz Force to create uV levels that need huge gain

Comment: Did you notice the units given for the hall effect voltage in that second video?  That's microvolts.  I don't think you are going to be measuring that with your handy dandy every day multimeter.

Comment: So you think the setup is okay? You’re thinking I’m just not able to detect the very small voltage.  That meter measures millivolts. I do have an oscilloscope and was unable to detect a voltage there ether. Is it possible that I need to apply a greater voltage across the plate, say 10 volts?

Comment: I'm saying that regardless of your setup, your measuring equipment isn't up to measuring the signal you could expect in the described experiment.

Comment: Wow! You’re right micro voltage. Wonder how Hall measured it in the 1800s. Good point though the video did say micro not milli.

Comment: [Hall used gold leaf, high voltage, and a Thomson quadrant electrometer](http://www.physics.utah.edu/~lebohec/P5510/References/Discovery_of_Hall_effect.pdf) to detect the effect for the first time.  The thinner the metal, the stronger the effect.  The Thomson electrometer is apparently very sensitive.  Higher voltage helped as well.   Now consider:  What was a major undertaking for Hall that required a laboratory full of expensive equipment has been reduced to a small, simple three legged part that Just Works(tm).  That's engineering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a Hall effect experiment that expects to see about 20 uV: -

[image]

[Extract from here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjX3vud_vjZAhWJLsAKHYeEAJUQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.phys.utk.edu%2Flabs%2Fmodphys%2FHall%2520Effect.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3CQzmSGZy7pUk1lnCojub7).

Answer (score 1):

Your picture does not describe a thousand words given here https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ip43wws6FEw

Perhaps you can use two insulated steel plates and measure the voltage when magnets are brought close across  the plates with a thin film of separation.